# How to make configuration read from an xml file available at configuration phase of gradle build?

Tags: gradle, build-process, gradle-plugin

I have a ton of ant projects which I want to migrate to gradle. All projects have in common a `config.xml` file. This file exists for reasons independent of the build, but I want to keep its information in a single place, so I evaluate it during the ant build as well.

I created a custom plugin with a PluginExtension and a ParserTask. The PluginExtension allows the user to provide the `config.xml` path as a propertie. The ParserTask locates the file automatically or using the provided path and parses the file if found. It then fills the remaining PluginExtension properties with the respective configuration data from `config.xml`.

This is working perfectly but has a major drawback: since parsing is done in a task, the respective properties of the PluginExtension are not filled with the information from `config.xml` during configuration phase of my build. This leads to all kind of smelly workarounds in my build file because I can't set the archives basename at configuration phase or configure the manifest in that phase, so I need to update this information during the execution phase.

How can I parse the `config.xml` during my build such that the properties are already filled with the correct values during configuration phase?

Moving the configuration information to a properties file and regenerating the `config.xml` during build time is NOT an option, because I need to maintain the ant build for a while as well. Additionally I need to `config.xml` file to be part of the version control.

Edit: despite having found an answer myself, I'm still interested in other responses, especially if they address the downside that I have left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now moved the parsing into the PluginExtension and called the parser from the PluginExtension Constructor. One downside is left. I can no longer configure where to search for the `config.xml` using that extension. Instead I have to rely entirely on file search. This is OK for my current use case.